# Speeding up the pageload of a page with a huge Matrix

Tags: matrix, speed

We've got a site with a navigation on top, which navigates to anchorpoints on the page, but the whole page is built with 1 matrix. The page will probably be very long and will have all kinds of images (small & big) in it. I've set image transforms, so images won't be a problem.
BUT: is it possible to speed up the site with lazyloading or something like that when there's 100+ matrix elements in it? 
And on that note I guess the biggest problem we'll face is having the anchor points still working: if they click the anchorpoint they should be able to scroll to that point, even if it's not visible yet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of a broad topic, but here are some resources to get your started:

- Great article on Craft optimizations here: http://www.patpohler.com/performance-optimization-craft-cms/
- Make sure your environment isn't a bottleneck.

  - You're not on an overloaded shared hosting server.
  - PHP has plenty of memory allocated to it.
  - Your server has plenty of resources (memory, CPU, disk space).
  - Run PHP 7.
- Eager load elements as necessary: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements
- Judiciously use template caching in Craft where necessary: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/cache
- Enable devMode and review the profile output in the browser's console (as well as `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files to spot any bottlenecks (# of queries, types of queries, plugins involved, etc.)
- Use [template hooks](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#hook-detail) as necessary.
- Go through the plethora of client side things that can slow a page down. [Google Pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) is a good place to start for that.
- If none of these work, you can looking into changing your content architecture so that 100+ Matrix blocks on one page aren't necessary.